# SAXParseException - The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:client'

Tags: java, spring, maven, cxf

I am using Spring framework 4.3.9, Apache CFX 2.3.0 and Maven 2.2.1 in only of my application. When I ran the application it works fine but when I ran the same application using Maven 3.x.x (3.3.1/3.5.2) getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:client'.
```

Below is the excerpt from context XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

When I check the tomcat webapps/app/lib folder all the required jars (cxf-api-2.3.0, cxf-codegen-plugin-2.3.0,cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws-2.3.0) are also copied there.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add context at the end of `xsi:schemaLocation`

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

If you have other namespace declarations, you should add them too.

Comment: Tried adding the context schema location, but still getting same error. With maven 2.2.1 its working fine, but with maven 3.x.x its throwing this error.